# User ID bot command

Tags: discord.py

I'm having some trouble with a user-finder command.
I probably have more errors than is what is showing up, but here are the ones I know of:

```
embed.add_field(name='User ID', value=text=str(user.id))
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Code :

@Client.command()
async def ui(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author    
    date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xA9A9A9, description='.ui <ID>')
    embed.set_author(name=str(user), icon_url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    if user.bot:
        embed.add_field(name="Bot? ", value='Yes')
    else:
        embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value='No')
    embed.add_field(name="Regiestered", value=user.created_at.strftime(date_format))
    embed.add_field(name='User ID', value=text=str(user.id))
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What was the point of `value=text=str(...)`? You're using `=` twice which is what is causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is `client.command()`, not `Client.command()`.

As **12944qwerty** stated in the comments there is no such `value=text=str(...)` as this is causing a `SyntaxError`.

**Take a look at the "new" code:**

```py
@client.command() # Client to client
async def ui(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xA9A9A9, description='.ui <ID>')
    embed.set_author(name=str(user), icon_url=user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    if user.bot:
        embed.add_field(name="Bot? ", value='Yes')
    else:
        embed.add_field(name="Bot?", value='No')
    embed.add_field(name="Regiestered", value=user.created_at.strftime(date_format))
    embed.add_field(name='User ID', value=f"{user.id}") # Used f-strings
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```